# How can I get the actual type of input:number in IE9-?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have given a type="number" to an INPUT tag, and I kown that IE9- didn't support number type. I try to make some js code to compactible to IE9-, so I test in IE11(and change compact mode to IE9).

But, when I want to get the type of a input:number, it always return 'text'. I tried these ways:

first, my html is:

```
<input name="field11" type="number" min="1" max="99">
```

then, I try to get the type, it should be `number` theoretically:

```
- input.type; // text
- input.getAttribute('type'); // text
- input.getAttributeNode('type').value;  //text
```

and css will not work either:

```
input[type="number"] {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

How Strange!

but, if i change the type to an **definitely** unsupported one, like `numberd`:

```
<input name="field11" type="numberd" min="1" max="99" >
```

all of above code will work correctly and show `numberd`!! Even I change css to `numberd` it will work too!! why?!

below is snippet:

```css
input[type="number"] {
    border: 1px solid #f00;
}
input[type="numberd"] {
    border: 1px solid #0f0;
}
```

```html
type="numberd" should be green border:
<input id="input1" type="numberd" min="1" max="99" onclick="alert(this.getAttribute('type'))" />
<br>
type="number", should be red border
<input id="input2" type="number" min="1" max="99" onclick="alert(this.getAttribute('type'))" />
```

At the end, my question is, how to get the actual type of the input:number in IE9-? Can somebody help me ?

Comment: @user8180795—that isn't a duplicate. This question is about markup with `<input type="number">` but `node.getAttribute('type')` on the related element showing *text* not *number*.

Comment: *getAttribute* should show the actual value of the attribute, so your assumptions seem appropriate. IE is letting you know how dangerous assumptions can be. ;-)

Comment: @user8180795  Not at all, my quesition has no relation with yours.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that you're having to do the same thing I just did and run IE11 in IE9 mode.  I know that IE9 treats unknown types as text, but I'm not 100% certain it would actually "convert" the type when adding the element.

I would not rely on the type attribute for what you want.  Instead, I would add a class to the inputs you want to verify and check for it.  You could also add a custom attribute and check for it.

Answer (score 0):

I think this quesition is a big problem and I can't find how to solve it by myself, and my quesition isn't similar with other's. but I can't get more answers or even views.

just 18 times view util now (half is from me). I think I will have no quesitions on stackoverflow. Bye guys, thanks for helps

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, when I try to just keep it numeric

In html `body` section:

`<input onkeyup="if(this.value=='-'){}else{if(isNaN(this.value)){this.value='';}}"></input>`

It will clear the input once it is not numeric..